# mongodb query an array within an array within an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, go, mgo

I have a collection of users. Each of those have an array of bookmarks. Each bookmark has an array of categories it belongs to. Leading to a structure like this:

```
[
    {name: "Bob",
     bookmarks: [
         {url: "http://duckduckgo.com",
          categories: [
              "Search",
              "Ducks",
          ],
         },
     ],
    },
]
```

Now given a name and a url and a category name. I want to delete said category of the respective bookmark. But my problem is that all attempts return the whole user or delete the whole bookmark and not just the category.

This is my best attempt using the mgo driver so far:

```
type arbitraryJson map[string]interface{}
user := "Bob"
bookmarkURL := url.Parse("http://duckduckgo.com")
tagName := "Search"

err = userDB.Update(
    arbitraryJson{
        "name":          user,
        "bookmarks.url": bookmarkURL.String(),
    },
    arbitraryJson{
        "$pull": arbitraryJson{
            "bookmarks.categories": tagName,
        },
    },
)
```

Which translates (I think) to the mongo query:

```
db.users.updateOne(
   { name: "Bob",
     bookmarks.url: "http://duckduckgo.com" }
   {
     $pull: { bookmarks.categories: "search" }
   }
)
```

Comment: have you tested the mongo query on any tool?

Comment: I also tried the nosqlclient interface but since it does exactly the same thing it also failed. Well more technically: it succeeded but didnt do the thing I hoped it did.

Comment: You could try to replace `arbitraryJson` with `bson.M`

Comment: Already tried. It not a fault of the data type.